# Docker Installation Error on Windows behind Firewall

Tags: windows, docker, installation, boot2docker

I'm trying to install Docker on a Windows computer but I get this message:

[image: Docker Quickstart Terminal Error Message]

> Running pre-create checks...
>   (default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
>   Error with pre-create check: "Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp 192.30.252.124:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
>   Looks like something went wrong in step 'Checking if machine default exists'...
>   Press any key to continue...

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Pasting the actual text rather than an image is preferred.  That way the error message can be textually indexed.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". Your question doesn't tell us enough of what you've already tried, so any attempts to help will likely rehash anything you've done, wasting everyone's time. Instead, tell us what you tried, what happened or why it didn't work.

Comment: @rrauenza yeah, I'm using a work computer so it's behind a firewall.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Editing the `start.sh` file may come up with other error things.

Instead that, just put your `boot2docker.iso` in below location as.

```
c:\user\USERNAME\\.docker\machine\cache
```

and restart your Docker terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You may behind a firewall.  If so, you will need to configure an http proxy.

According to https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/230 you can do this one of a couple of ways:

(1) Edit `start.sh` and add the following before `boot2docker.exe` is called

```
export HTTP_PROXY=<proxy>
export HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy>
```

(2) Add `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` (and their values) to your System Variables or User Variables in your Windows config.

The proxy value should be of the form `http://hostname:port`

Comment: The start.sh file is read only so I don't think it can be edited

Comment: @AmyWang I was able to edit it fine. The above solution worked for me.