# How to resolve docker startup issue in toolbox

Tags: docker, daemon

I am new to docker. I have installed docker toolbox in my machine, as I have windows 7. It properly installed docker toolbox with oracle virtual box also. When I start docker toolbox I get the log as follows:

```
Running pre-create checks...
(default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest relea
se...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v18.09.4
(default) Downloading C:\Users\<Mypath>\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso from
 https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.09.4/boot2docker.iso...
```

It waits for a very long time at the same state.

It waits while downloading the boot2docker.iso, so I tried downloading the iso file manually and placed inside the "cache" folder. But still it stops at this point.

It should download the iso file and docker should work as expected.

Comment: you cna go into virtualbox and create a new virtua, machine then add the boot2docker iso as a drive and boot it this will allow it to isntall

Comment: `docker toolbox` is considered legacy and do not meet the requirements of Docker Desktop for Windows. If possible move to newer solutions.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl- i tried it now, but when i start docker toolbox and the same issue occurs. :(

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand- As of now I am supposed to work on this only, and no other go for me. That's why I am trying to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same error. I went to the folder c:\user\USERNAME\.docker\machine\cache and checked for boot2docker.iso file.

The file is present but it asked for administrator rights when i clicked. After i gave ok my docker works now

You can also refer to this

[Docker Installation Error on Windows behind Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620347/docker-installation-error-on-windows-behind-firewall)